# Oracle Analytics Window Function

Tags: oracle, window

If I have some data like so:

```
MyDate    LEVEL
01JAN2016 5.1
02JAN2016 6.2
03JAN2016 8.0
04JAN2016 5.8
```

How can I use a windowing function to return the date with the highest level ?
I was thinking:

SELECT max(MyDate) over (ORDER BY LEVEL) FROM x

... but it doesnt seem to work. I Tried using PARTITION BY but still no luck. I really want max(LEVEL).

Answer (score 1):

```
select mydate, level
from (select mydate, level, row_number() over (order by level desc) rn from x)
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use fancy functions . . .

```
select max(date) keep (dense_rank first order by level desc)
from x;
```

However, many people would write:

```
select x.*
from (select x.*
      from x
      order by level desc
     ) x
where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: lol - good guess!  :-)  And I edited to add "desc" after I saw your post - I missed it in the first reading in the question.